# How to get friends count of an random user in Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the friend count of a random user in Facebook?

I was trying to make a request 
at

```
1579961218908589/friends
```

on the Graph API Explorer and it always gives me empty data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends) for that endpoint, you'll be able to see that retrieving the friends of an user requires that person to enable your app's permission to do so.

So the answer is yes, if you have the permission from the user, or no, otherwise.

If you have the required permissions, then the JSON response will look the same as it does for `me/friends`.

The response will generally look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Friend Name", 
      "id": "1579961218908589"
    }, 
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": ""
  }, 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 317
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think: no.
You're able to get **total_count** field only for people who uses your application.

> Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app. [Learn More](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0)

Comment: It's not correct what you are writing, and you even cite the FB docs.